# Mongoose + Typescript -> Exporting model interface

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I want to export only my model's interfaces instead of the Document so that nobody can modify my model if it's not inside it's own class methods. I have defined the interface and the schema like this:

IUser:

```
interface IUser {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  created_at: number;
  updated_at: number;
  last_login: number;
}
```

And the Schema:

```
let userSchema: Mongoose.Schema = new Mongoose.Schema({
   'name': String,
   'email': String,
   'created_at': {'type': Date, 'default': Date.now},
   'updated_at': {'type': Date, 'default': Date.now},
   'last_login': {'type': Number, 'default': 0},
});

interface UserDocument extends IUser, Mongoose.Document {}
```

And then the model

```
// Model
let Users: Mongoose.Model<UserDocument> = Mongoose.model<UserDocument>('User', userSchema);
```

So i just export the IUser and a class User that basically has all the methods to update my model.

The problem is that typescript complains if i add the _id to my interface, but i actually need it, otherwise i will need to pass the UserDocument and that's what i didn't wanted  to do. The error typescript gives me is:

**error TS2320: Interface 'UserDocument' cannot simultaneously extend types 'IUser' and 'Document'.
  Named property '_id' of types 'IUser' and 'Document' are not identical.**

Any ideas how i can add the _id property to my interface?

Thanks!

Comment: `_id` in Mongoose is, by default, of type `ObjectId` (`mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`).

Comment: Hi @robertklep, i tried that already instead of string, and it gives me the same error, only if i put _id: any it stops complaining, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Too bad :( I have no experience with TS whatsoever so can't help you any further I'm afraid.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try:

```
interface UserDocument extends IUser, Mongoose.Document {
   _id: string;
}
```

It will resolve the conflict between IUser._id (string) vs Mongoose.Document._id (any).

**Update**:

As pointed out in comments, currently it gives a `incompatible override for member from "Document"`, so another workaround must be used. [Intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) is a solution that can be used. That said, the following can be done:

```
type UserDocument = IUser & Mongoose.Document;
```

Alternatively, if you do not want `UserDocument` anymore:

```
// Model
let Users = Mongoose.model<IUser & Mongoose.Document>('User', userSchema);
```

It is worth noting that there is a side effect in this solution. The conflicting properties will have the types intersected, so `IUser._id (string) & Mongoose.Document._id (any)` results in `UserDocument._id (any)`, for example.

Comment: You sure?  This gives `incompatible override for member from "Document"`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the conflicting part? 
```It is worth noting that there is a side effect in this solution. The conflicting properties will have the types intersected, so IUser._id (string) & Mongoose.Document._id (any) results in UserDocument._id (any),```

Answer (score 2):

I just had this exact issue, where I wanted to keep the User interface properties as separate from Mongoose as possible. I managed to solve the problem using the [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type.

Here is your original code using that type:

```js
import { Document, Model, ObjectId } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser {
  _id: ObjectId;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  created_at: number;
  updated_at: number;
  last_login: number;
}

export interface IUserDocument extends Omit<IUser, '_id'>, Document {}
export interface IUserModel extends Model<IUserDocument> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
   ..
  }
);
type UserDoc = IUser & Document;

export interface UserDocument extends UserDoc {}

// For model
export interface UserModel extends Model<UserDocument> {}

export default model<UserDocument>("User", UserSchema);
```